# Deploying sharepoint applications using the API to a web collection

Tags: c#, sharepoint, deployment

I'm trying to use the sharepoint API to deploy some solutions and the global DLLs work fine with solution.deploy, but im having trouble with solutions that specificy a web application.

I have a webapplication test and want to deploy to it, but the deploy command needs a web application collection, and im not sure how these relate or work, 
I've spent hours trying to find a guide to writing an API based install or similar but with no luck..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a generic collection of URI's.  One for each web application you need to deploy the solution to.

[A code sample can be seen here.](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Patrick/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1721)

Comment: Oh its so obvious now! Thank you very much :)